# what does the redundancy of a code means?

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory, error-correcting-codes

I was reading a paper about a transposition and single deletion error correcting code and they claim that the redundancy of the code *was only* $\log(6n-3)$ bits.

But *what does that means?* I was trying to get that from the proof of that fact but what they proved instead was that

*there exists a such (with the structure they propose) code whose redundancy is at most* $\log(6n-3)$ *bits*

and in the proof itself they just said that the cardinality of the code is greater or equal than $\frac{2^n}{6n-3}$.

How does that proved the hypothesis?

Also, if I have my own code how do I compute the redundancy (or a reasonable bound on it?)

Comment: What paper were you reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [linear error-correcting code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_code) encodes $m$ message bits using $w$ encoded bits. The redundancy is $r = w-m$. In other words, it is a collection of $M = 2^m$ codewords out of the possible $W = 2^w$ words of length $w$. We can extract the redundancy using the formula
$$ r = \log_2 \frac{W}{M}. $$
This formula makes sense for arbitrary error-correcting codes.

In your case, codewords are of length $n$, and there are at least $2^n/(6n-3)$ of them. Therefore the redundancy is at most
$$ \log_2 \frac{2^n}{2^n/(6n-3)} = \log_2 (6n-3). $$

Comment: thanks for your answer, I think this formula works as well for non linear codes, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I wrote in the answer.